# Map in Hibernate a table to MEMORY (HEAP) in XML

Tags: java, hibernate

This question is not about caching.
I need this in-memory table for many small updates and complicated queries.
I must have it on a server shared between several nodes.

MySQL have [MEMORY (HEAP) Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html) which is exactly what I need.

Can I tell Hibernate to create such a table, when defining a `<class>` or a '` in the XML?
Is there another solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot generate those tables via Hibernate. Hibernate chooses storage engine based to dialect, and for MySQL 5 available dialects are [MySQL5InnoDBDialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL5InnoDBDialect.html) and [MySQL5Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL5Dialect.html).

If it is really important to generate database structure via Hibernate, then you can of course go and create dialect yourself. As you see from the [source of MySQL5InnoDBDialect](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.1.3.Final/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL5InnoDBDialect.java#MySQL5InnoDBDialect), it boils down to "ENGINE = MEMORY".

Comment: Nice idea, I like it a lot and might go for it. Thank you!